# Fast tree evaluating

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, high-load

I have an evaluating tree class. Each node has children in a strict order. A server has a list of such trees.

When a client successfully connects to the server, it sends a lot of different `HashMaps` to a selected tree for computation. Typical `HashMap`s have pairs: [Variable string name, Variable int value].

Each `TreeNode` has a complex condition, which can read variables and has operations such as AND, OR, XOR, comparing with other variables or numbers.  Each `TreeNode` also has statements, which can read/write variables and put new variables to `HashMap`s, which can subsequently be read/written in another `TreeNode`.

Here is a simplified structure of the trees:

```java
public static class TreeNode {
    public static abstract class Condition {
        public abstract boolean evaluate(HashMap<String, Integer> contex);
    }

    public static abstract class Statement {
        public abstract void execute(HashMap<String, Integer> contex);
    }

    private Condition condition;
    private List<Statement> statements;
    private List<TreeNode> children;

    public void run(final HashMap<String, Integer> contex) {
        if (condition != null && !condition.evaluate(contex)) {
            return;
        }

        for (final Statement statement : statements) {
            statement.execute(contex);
        }

        for (final TreeNode child : children) {
            child.run(contex);
        }
    }
}
```

My code currently performs about 200000 iterations/sec on an Intel i7 u3517 for a tree with 100 nodes and an input `HashMap` with 10 variables.  How can I speed it up?

Comment: The code you presented does not afford any obvious opportunities for performance improvement.  As with any performance issue, you should profile some executions of the program to evaluate which parts are actually slowing you down.  Don't neglect time consumed by the GC.

Comment: How are the `Statement`s and `Condition`s constructed? Is there any room for optimisation? Are any of the keys used depending on the `HashMap`'s content and/or the state of a object (e.g. a field in one of the `Statement`s)? Is the tree ever modified? I don't see any room for optimisation for arbitrary `Condition`s and `Statement`s and trees that are modified. But if there are some restrictions...

Comment: @fabian, `Statement`s and `Condition`s are constructed like binary trees. For example, condition "x == 3 and y < 5" consist of 3 nodes: 1 node checks (x==3), 1 node checks (y<5) and 1 node, which is parent, invokes `evaluate` methods of its children and make AND. Similarly `Statement`s work with "x = 3 + y * 5". Tree cannot be modified during computation, when client uses it.

Comment: @fabian, `Statement`s can only modify `HashMap`'s content. For example, if `statements[i]` puts a new variable, all `statements[j]`, which has j > i, and all `child.statements` can read that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your statements and children can be run in parallel and you are using Java 8 you could use `parallelStream()`.

```
        statements.parallelStream().forEach((statement) -> {
            statement.execute(contex);
        });

        children.parallelStream().forEach((child) -> {
            child.run(contex);
        });
```

Comment: Well yes, or it could be parallelized differently in earlier versions of Java.  However, I take the OP's emphasis on the "strict order" of child nodes as an indication that they must be evaluated serially.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Agreed - and I would certainly support your suggestion to measure before cutting. Perhaps only the statements will parallelise.